# Как правильно создать сессионный бин?

Tags: servlet, java, ejb

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде сессионных бинов. Но работает приложение непредсказуемо. Сервлет примерно такой:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/goservlet.jsp"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private MySessionBean mySessionBean;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
              throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Устанавливаем параметр. Текущий=" + mySessionBean.getStr1());
        mySessionBean.setStr1(request.getParameter("xaction"));
        response.sendRedirect("/zapros.jsp");

}
... ... ...
```

Бин у меня `Stateful`:

```
@Stateful(name = "MySessionEJB")
public class MySessionBean {
    private String str;
...
```

Вроде, для всех сессий должен быть свой собственный объект `MySessionBean`. Но при отладке, когда с разных компьютеров отправляются запросы на сервер к этому сервлету, то и для одной и для другой сессии (для одного и второго пользователя) используется один и тот же объект `MySessionBean`. А именно, если один пользователь изменит поле объекта, то и у другого пользователя произойдут такие же изменения. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь или скажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы думаете, что HTTP-сессии и сессии EJB имеют между собой что-то общее. На самом деле, они не обязаны как-то коррелироваться. У EJB-бинов собственный жизненный цикл и регулируется он EJB-контейнером независимо от веб-контейнера. В частности, EJB-контейней имеет внутри пул экземпляров бина и часто один и тот же экземпляр бина переиспользуется так что значения могут сохраняться даже у stateless бинов, хоть они и не обязаны ничего такого делать.

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста, тогда каким же красивым образом можно можно добиться того, чтобы для каждой сессии были свои объекты? Может, какие-то библиотеки и/или стандарты имеются?

Comment: Если вы хотите привязать что-то именно к HTTP-сессии, то вы можете вставить простой бин в сессиию как аттрибут. Тогда в последствии его можно будет также использовать из JSP через EL.

Comment: Ну ясно. Видимо, в любом случае надо заносить в сессию. Просто в JSF2 был реализован такой удобный механизм. Я даже и не задумывался на счет сессий. Просто ставил @SessionScoped и для каждой сессии объект этого класса - свой.